# Entity Framework .Core treating foreign key as a primary key

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have the two classes shown below. When trying to insert two `HeroEntry` with the same `IdentityId`, the context is only saving one of the two entries. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
public class Identity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int IdentityId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual HeroEntry HeroEntry { get; set; }
}

public class HeroEntry
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int HeroEntryId { get; set; }
    public int IdentityId { get; set; }
    public SuperHeroEnum HeroType { get; set; }
    public DateTime Startdate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdentityId")]
    public virtual Identity Identity { get; set; }
    public virtual List<SuperHeroBreak> SuperHeroBreaks { get; set; }
}
```

Add code:

```
var b = new HeroEntry()
            {
                HeroType = SuperHeroEnum.BATMAN,
                Startdate = DateTime.Parse("12/24/2018"),
                EndDate = DateTime.Parse("01/04/2019"),
                IdentityId = 1,
            };

var r = new HeroEntry()
            {
                HeroType = SuperHeroEnum.ROBIN,
                Startdate = DateTime.Parse("12/24/2018"),
                EndDate = DateTime.Parse("01/04/2019"),
                IdentityId = 1,
            };

context.SuperHeroes.AddRange(b, r);

var affected = context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: could you post the add code?

Comment: Sorry, added.  I am expecting affected to return 2 but it is returning 1.

Comment: what if you add records by single insert?

Comment: I tried adding one by one as well as adding and saving then adding and saving again.  Same result.

Comment: You have `one-to-one` relationship defined between tables. Verify if there is a constraint defined for the `IdentityId` property.

Comment: Cristian Szpisjak is right... you should have a collection of  HeroEntry inside identity object (a navigation property)

Comment: see that: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: What’s this [JustIgnore]? Could you explain the relationship between the tables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cristian was correct.  Adding the navigation property to the identity class solved my issue.  Thank you for the help!